# How to display specified rows using vue js?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

This is the data I obatined from the url. I need to print only the 2nd and the 4th row,

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "source": "n",
    "sortBy": "top",
    "articles": [
        {
            "author": "Bradford ",
            "title": "friends.",
            "url": "http: //",
            "urlToImage": "http://"
        },
        {
            "author": "Bradford  ",
            "title": "Kershaw threw six mesmerizing innings to put L.A. into the Fall Classic.",
            "url": "http: //",
            "urlToImage": "http://"
        },
              "author": "Bord  ",
            "title": "Kershaw threw six mesmerizing innings to put L.A. into the Fall Classic.",
            "url": "http: //",
            "urlToImage": "http://"
        },
             "author": "Brad  ",
            "title": "Kershaw threw six mesmerizing innings to put L.A. into the Fall Classic.",
            "url": "http: //",
            "urlToImage": "http://"
        }
    ]
}
```

My vue js script is given below. This is how I retrieve the value from the corresponding url

```
 <script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#feed' ,
        data: {
        articles: [],
        },
        mounted() {
        this.$nextTick(function() {
          var self = this;
          $.ajax({
                url: "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=espn&sortBy=top&apiKey=4db9d5d381a14ffcbca8e8a9aa8b864c",
                method: "GET",
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function (e) {
                    if (e.status == 'ok') {
                        self.articles = e.articles;
                        console.log(e.articles)
                    }
                }, error: function(){
                console.log('Error occurred');
                }
            });
        })
        },
       })
</script>
```

MY HTML IS

```
<div id="feed">
<div v-for="post in articles" class="mke_">
  <div class="row">
      {{post.title}}
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Please help me to display only the 2nd and 4th articles[]? 
I am weak in js. So, it will great to help me out

Comment: How do you determine that you need 2nd and 4th rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By 2nd and 4th row, I presume you mean that the elements at index 1 and 3. The simplest way of doing so would be to add a `v-if` binding with the following condition: `articles.indexOf(post) == 1 || articles.indexOf(post) == 3`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#feed',
  data: {
    articles: [{
        "author": "Bradford ",
        "title": "friends.",
        "url": "http: //",
        "urlToImage": "http://"
      },
      {
        "author": "Bradford  ",
        "title": "Kershaw threw six mesmerizing innings to put L.A. into the Fall Classic.",
        "url": "http: //",
        "urlToImage": "http://"
      }, {
        "author": "Bord  ",
        "title": "Kershaw threw six mesmerizing innings to put L.A. into the Fall Classic.",
        "url": "http: //",
        "urlToImage": "http://"
      },
      {
        "author": "Brad  ",
        "title": "Kershaw threw six mesmerizing innings to put L.A. into the Fall Classic.",
        "url": "http: //",
        "urlToImage": "http://"
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="feed">
  <div v-for="post in articles" v-if="articles.indexOf(post) == 1 || articles.indexOf(post) == 3" class="mke_">
    <div class="row">
      {{post.title}}
      <br/>
      <small>{{post.author}}</small>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In order to separate the UI from logic, you can use a computed for the purpose. The computed can filter the required values like:

```
return this.articles.filter(t => 
    this.articles.indexOf(t) == 1 
    || this.articles.indexOf(t) == 3
);
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#feed',
  data: {
    articles: [{
        "author": "Bradford ",
        "title": "friends.",
        "url": "http: //",
        "urlToImage": "http://"
      },
      {
        "author": "Bradford  ",
        "title": "Kershaw threw six mesmerizing innings to put L.A. into the Fall Classic.",
        "url": "http: //",
        "urlToImage": "http://"
      }, {
        "author": "Bord  ",
        "title": "Kershaw threw six mesmerizing innings to put L.A. into the Fall Classic.",
        "url": "http: //",
        "urlToImage": "http://"
      },
      {
        "author": "Brad  ",
        "title": "Kershaw threw six mesmerizing innings to put L.A. into the Fall Classic.",
        "url": "http: //",
        "urlToImage": "http://"
      }
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    filteredPosts() {
      return this.articles.filter(t => this.articles.indexOf(t) == 1 || this.articles.indexOf(t) == 3);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="feed">
  <div v-for="post in filteredPosts" class="mke_">
    <div class="row">
      {{post.title}}
      <br/>
      <small>{{post.author}}</small>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** I've added in the post author to the display in order to make it easier to know the index of filtered items.

### Update

[As suggested by Bert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46865057/how-to-display-specified-rows-using-vue-js/46865218?noredirect=1#comment80680361_46865218), the filter can be improved to:

```
return this.articles.filter((t, i) => 
    i == 1 || i == 3
);
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#feed',
  data: {
    articles: [{
        "author": "Bradford ",
        "title": "friends.",
        "url": "http: //",
        "urlToImage": "http://"
      },
      {
        "author": "Bradford  ",
        "title": "Kershaw threw six mesmerizing innings to put L.A. into the Fall Classic.",
        "url": "http: //",
        "urlToImage": "http://"
      }, {
        "author": "Bord  ",
        "title": "Kershaw threw six mesmerizing innings to put L.A. into the Fall Classic.",
        "url": "http: //",
        "urlToImage": "http://"
      },
      {
        "author": "Brad  ",
        "title": "Kershaw threw six mesmerizing innings to put L.A. into the Fall Classic.",
        "url": "http: //",
        "urlToImage": "http://"
      }
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    filteredPosts() {
      return this.articles.filter((t,i) => i == 1 || i == 3);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="feed">
  <div v-for="post in filteredPosts" class="mke_">
    <div class="row">
      {{post.title}}
      <br/>
      <small>{{post.author}}</small>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No sir, I need to print all the values of articles array.

Comment: In this example   {
        "author": "Bradford  ",
        "title": "Kershaw threw six mesmerizing innings to put L.A. into the Fall Classic.",
        "url": "http: //",
        "urlToImage": "http://"
      }                                                                                                        
    {
        "author": "Brad  ",
        "title": "Kershaw threw six mesmerizing innings to put L.A. into the Fall Classic.",
        "url": "http: //",
        "urlToImage": "http://"
      }

Comment: In the question you've written: *I need to print only the 2nd and the 4th row*. What do you mean by that??

Comment: Please check that url. There are many datas. My objective is to print only few of these

Comment: By row I mean the 2nd and 4th values of the articles array

Comment: I'm slightly confused here. Could you edit the question to demonstrate how the output should look like?

Comment: @NisargShah, you've got an issue in your code snippet (`Vue` is undefined). Thanks to fix it.

Comment: Sir, actually my problem is as follows::: If we are using v-for as I used all the values that comes inside articles [ ] are getting printed. I need only few array values to be printed. Sometimes I need to print values inside 2nd index only. In some other cases I need both values inside 2nd and 4th index. Can you please show it using the vue script

Comment: @Philicare It works fine for me. Any chance the CDN is being blocked in your network?

Comment: `indexOf` is unnecessary here. The filter callback receives the index as a parameter. `(t,i) => i == 1 || i == 3`

Comment: Or better yet, ` return [this.articles[1], this.articles[3]]`. This one doesn't have to loop through the whole array.